# How get yesterday in Haskell? Current date - 1 day?

Tags: haskell

How get **yesterday** in Haskell? For the current day - of course it works like this:

```
date :: IO (Integer,Int,Int) -- :: (year,month,day)
date = getCurrentTime >>= return . toGregorian . utctDay
```

But for yesterday? Does that work with diffUTCTime?

With sql:

```
select current date, current date - 1 day from sysdba.routine 
08.11.2018 07.11.2018
```

But with Haskell?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [**`addUTCTime :: NominalDiffTime -> UTCTime -> UTCTime`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/time-1.9.2/docs/Data-Time-Clock.html#v:addUTCTime) function with as difference [**`-nominalDay`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/time-1.9.2/docs/Data-Time-Clock.html#v:nominalDay). For example:

```
Prelude Data.Time.Clock> fmap (addUTCTime (-nominalDay)) getCurrentTime
2018-11-07 15:27:57.8510597 UTC
```

or when you want to obtain the Gregorian date:

```
Prelude Data.Time.Clock Data.Time.Calendar> fmap (toGregorian . utctDay . addUTCTime (-nominalDay)) getCurrentTime
(2018,11,7)
```

Comment: @Elmex80s: as far as I know UTCTime is not an instance of `Enum`.

Comment: I wouldn't expect it to work for times, but it might be interesting to find out if it could work for dates.

Comment: `fmap` can be replaced with `<$>`: `addUTCTime (-nominalDay) <$> getCurrentTime`